# How to access OpenRPA project file where the OpenRPA project and its workflows are stored?

Tags: testing, rpa

We are trying to quickly setup and test OpenRPA project, but the handling of the project/workflows information is very strange. I can create new project and workflows within it, but there are no 'Save As' button for this project.

Where the project is saved and how can I more this project from one workstation to another? I think that this should be pretty basic activity, just grab file or directory and copy/paste on another computer and then load/import/open it in the OpenRPA tool. But there are not commands/menu entries for such activities? How to do this?

I am aware of the documentation https://docs.openiap.io/openrpa.html#create-new-project and it suggests that something is stored in 'My Documents', but there are just general settins.json, layout.config and some *.db files. Maybe projects/workflows are stores in those db files and then I should somehow get projects/workflows out of those db files?

Such subtle issues make the OpenRPA adoption very heavy.

Comment: OpenRPA community has dedicated forum which is really helpful. This forum has also answer to my question https://discourse.openiap.io/t/how-to-access-openrpa-project-file-where-the-openrpa-project-and-its-workflows-are-stored/589